# serilog not writing logs into local app data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I am trying to write log into "LocalApplicationData" using `Serilog` and using below configuration, but it's **not** working. If I try to write in some hard code path like `"path": "C:/Temp/Logs/log.txt"` then this is working. How to write into local app data folder?

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/Logs/log.txt",
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": "5242880",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "retainedFileCountLimit": "15",
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This format is used in NLog. The equivalent is to use %LOCALAPPDATA% instead:

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "%LOCALAPPDATA%/Logs/log.txt",
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": "5242880",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "retainedFileCountLimit": "15",
```

Please note that this will only work in `appSettings.json`. To do the equivalent in C# you can use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData")`